# Spring RestTemplate call fails intermittently with 'SocketException: Connection reset'

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, httpclient, spring-rest

The following exception i am getting when our application is consuming the Rest endpoint using spring boot RestTemplate.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://xxxxxxxxxx:123456/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx": 
Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 
Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:684)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:466)
```

This issue we are getting intermittently. some time more than 2 to 3 times.

I couldn't find any information specific to this issue ?

Does any one faced same issue and how its resolved?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We've been seeing the same issue. We added some terrible annotation, but doesn't resolve the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do the CURL on the endpoint you are trying to access using RESTTemplate and see if your machine has access to that URL?
If Yes-->Let me know and still getting an error, Let me know I will update the answer:)
If No-->that the problem I had the same issue for facebook API.